# Writing to a file from an array list and Vice Versa

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, outputstream, file-handling

I have created a small program with 3 buttons and 1 text field for user input. What the program does is, it takes input from the user and stores it to an arraylist, then when the second button is pressed it should write the arraylist in to the file. When the third button is pressed it should read from the file in to an arraylist.

My problem is am getting only the first record , meaning if i enter 2 names , i only get the first name displayed when i press the third button.
Here is what i have done:

2 arraylists are decalred.

```
 ArrayList<Person>list=new ArrayList<Person>()                                  ArrayList<Person>list2=new ArrayList<Person>();
```

The button which takes user input when pressed

```
   String firstname=txtname.getText();

   Person p1=new Person(firstname,"pamodya","15","08","1995");

    list.add(p1);
```

The button which writes the first arraylist object in to the file.
      try{

```
        FileOutputStream write=new FileOutputStream("hello.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream writeFile=new ObjectOutputStream(write);

       writeFile.writeObject(list);
      writeFile.flush();
     writeFile.close();

       }catch(Exception e){e.getMessage();}
```

The button which reads from the file and prints to the text area when pressed.

```
 try{
            FileInputStream read=new FileInputStream("hello.txt");
           ObjectInputStream readFile=new ObjectInputStream(read);


           Person p1=(Person)readFile.readObject();

          list2.add(p1);

          readFile.close();

          txtarea.setText(p1.getName());


    }catch(Exception e){e.getMessage();}
```

What seems to be the problem here? 
Thank you for your time.

EDIT :

This is the error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing a `list` but reading a `Person`. You should be getting a `ClassCastException` given the code.

Compare these two:

```
 writeFile.writeObject(list);
 Person p1=(Person)readFile.readObject();
```

you should use:

```
 List<Person> outList=(List)readFile.readObject();
 list2.addAll(outList);
```

Comment: I have uploaded a screen shot of the error, i cant get a stacktrace because the program won't compile

Comment: Use, `ArrayList<Person> outList = (ArrayList) readFile.readObject();`

Comment: Thank you it worked, can you please explain me what you are doing here?
As far as i understand you convert the object to a type "ArrayList" and then you assign it to a ArrayList type Person.

Am i correct?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it looks to me like you're not looping through any results at your third button. You just take the first result found and display it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a list of things to make sure of:

1) Is your Person class serializable?
2) When you open the file do you open it for appending?
3) I noticed you write the list object. But you read the Person object.